# Google Cloud Functions app doesn't write custom logs

Tags: google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-logging

Recently I've set up an application in Google Cloud Functions. It's a pet project, I just want to get a grasp on how things work on this platform. I'm trying to write custom application logs. I run the exact same code as given in an example [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#writing_runtime_logs):

```
function entryPoint(ServerRequestInterface $request): string
{
    $log = fopen('php://stderr', 'wb');

    fwrite($log, "Log entry from fwrite().\n");

    fwrite($log, json_encode([
            'message' => 'Structured log with error severity',
            'severity' => 'error'
        ]) . PHP_EOL);

    fwrite(
        log,
        json_encode([
            'logName' => 'projects/lyrical-bolt-XXX/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions',
            'resource' => [
                'type' => 'cloud_function',
                'labels' => [
                    'project_id' => 'lyrical-bolt-XXX',
                    'function_name' => 'index',
                    'region' => 'europe-central2'
                ]
            ],
            'textPayload' => 'Hello, Vasya! How are you??'
        ]) . PHP_EOL
    );

    return '';
}
```

Then I open Logs Explorer but my logs are just not there:
[image]

Am I missing anything? Maybe there are any permissions that I should grant to anything? If so, where exactly can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Your code works for me. I replaced your 3rd log with a `debug`:

```sh
gcloud functions logs read test \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Yields:

```
LEVEL  NAME  EXECUTION_ID  TIME_UTC                 LOG
D      test  ppg5pq2nle4b  2021-07-07 17:43:46.364  Function execution took 9 ms, finished with status code: 200
       test  ppg5pq2nle4b  2021-07-07 17:43:46.363  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:46] WARNING: [pool app] child 19 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with debug severity","severity":"debug"}"
       test  ppg5pq2nle4b  2021-07-07 17:43:46.363  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:46] WARNING: [pool app] child 19 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with error severity","severity":"error"}"
       test  ppg5pq2nle4b  2021-07-07 17:43:46.363  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:46] WARNING: [pool app] child 19 said into stderr: "Log entry from fwrite()."
D      test  ppg5pq2nle4b  2021-07-07 17:43:46.355  Function execution started
D      test  ppg579syhkvj  2021-07-07 17:43:45.126  Function execution took 3 ms, finished with status code: 200
       test  ppg579syhkvj  2021-07-07 17:43:45.126  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:45] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with error severity","severity":"error"}"
       test  ppg579syhkvj  2021-07-07 17:43:45.126  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:45] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "Log entry from fwrite()."
       test  ppg579syhkvj  2021-07-07 17:43:45.126  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:45] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with debug severity","severity":"debug"}"
D      test  ppg579syhkvj  2021-07-07 17:43:45.123  Function execution started
D      test  ppg56xpfu1ym  2021-07-07 17:43:43.859  Function execution took 118 ms, finished with status code: 200
       test  ppg56xpfu1ym  2021-07-07 17:43:43.856  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:43] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with debug severity","severity":"debug"}"
       test  ppg56xpfu1ym  2021-07-07 17:43:43.856  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:43] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "{"message":"Structured log with error severity","severity":"error"}"
       test  ppg56xpfu1ym  2021-07-07 17:43:43.856  [07-Jul-2021 17:43:43] WARNING: [pool app] child 17 said into stderr: "Log entry from fwrite()."
D      test  ppg56xpfu1ym  2021-07-07 17:43:43.742  Function execution started
I      test                2021-07-07 17:43:13.164  [pid1-nginx] Starting nginx (pid 18): /usr/sbin/nginx -c /tmp/nginxconf-466886520/nginx.conf
I      test                2021-07-07 17:43:13.158  [pid1-nginx] Successfully connected to /tmp/google-config/app.sock after 251.013037ms
       test                2021-07-07 17:43:12.951  [serve] Running /bin/sh -c exec php-fpm -R --nodaemonize --fpm-config /tmp/serve-php-051025325/php-fpm.conf
       test                2021-07-07 17:43:12.950  [serve] workersFromArgs: memoryMB:256 flagAppWorkers:0 workers:2
       test                2021-07-07 17:43:12.945  [serve] Could not parse memory limit; defaulting to 256MiB.
```

> **NOTE** You do not include the Google Logging `logName`, `resource` etc. properties. This is metadata that wraps what you write to stdout and stderr

> **NOTE** You have a typo on line #17 `fwrite(log,` should be `fwrite($log,`

Comment: It's great indeed that it works for you, but for some weird reason it doesn't work for me... Crazy enough, maybe free trial status is the reason? The other one I thought of is no less crazy: probably europe-central2 region does not support logging in php? Anyways, I'm writing to gc support right now.

Comment: My intent was to demonstrate that, everything else being equal, your code is good and the solution *should* work. I suspect you must enable billing for logs.